# How can I run request with model name and filter set as strings?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How on laravel 9 site can I run request with model name and filter set as strings :

```
runRequest(model: \App\Models\Vote::class, filter:"status = 'A'");


public function runRequest(string $model, string $filter)
{
        $data = $model::whereRaw($filter)
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->get();
}
```

But error was raised :

```
 Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

How to make it working?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
   App::make($model)
           ->query()
            ->whereRaw($filter)
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->get()
```

Comment: I tried in this way, bot got error : 
  Illegal offset type in isset or empty

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1289
    1285▕      * @return string
    1286▕      */
    1287▕     public function getAlias($abstract)
    1288▕     {
  ➜ 1289▕         return isset($this->aliases[$abstract])
    1290▕                     ? $this->getAlias($this->aliases[$abstract])
    1291▕                     : $abstract;
    1292▕     }
    1293▕